# Gremlin: Between function

Tags: gremlin

Sample data: [Modern graph](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/images/tinkerpop-modern.png)

I am trying to do starts with search,

This returns marko

```
gremlin> g.V().has("name", between("m", "mz")).values("name")
==>marko
```

This returns none

```
gremlin> g.V().has("name", between("m", "ma")).values("name")
gremlin>
```

**So is that I have to always use "z"? or what is the logic of using "z" in the between function. I don't find any documentation for the same.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was silently corrected by the [Gremlin Guru](https://about.me/daniel.kuppitz) on that answer I'd given (it's updated now), but the second argument to `between` is exclusive so if you want all "name" that start with "m" then you need the second argument to be "n".

Comment: To add more clarity I am doing a search like starts with `mar` so my query is `g.V().has("name", between("mar", "marz")).values("name")` and I get the data correctly

Comment: that's fine. as long as you realize that if there is someone named "marzo" in your data, that person will be excluded from your lookup if you write your query that way.

Comment: okay thanks. would be great if gremlin had some wildcard like search.

Comment: yes I tested, not able to fetch `marzo` with between("mar", "marz")